# Insufficient permissions for all users - how to change user settings at database level?

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamics-crm-2011

I just installed MS CRM 2011, customized it, imported a lot of data and then I changed some settings regarding: teams, business units, user roles etc. After refreshing, all users were locked out.

We are now trying to reset the user settings through the SQL database, but we are not sure which tables to edit and how?

Comment: Please post the actual error from the trace directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Moved from my original, "cleaner" answer).

It is possible that the OP removed the System Admin role from all users (TBC). If so, using SQL to restore this role to a user is **still unsupported**, but relatively easy to do:

```sql
-- Get id of sys admin role:
SELECT RoleId from [YourOrg_MSCRM].dbo.RoleBase where Name = 'System Administrator'

-- Get id of user to grant access
SELECT systemuserid from [YourOrg_MSCRM].dbo.SystemUserBase where DomainName = 'MyDomain\MyUser'

-- Check role is not already granted (result should be 0)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [YourOrg_MSCRM].dbo.SystemUserRoles WHERE RoleId = '[Id of Role]' AND SystemUserId = '[Id of user]'

-- Insert role against that user
INSERT INTO [YourOrg_MSCRM].[dbo].[SystemUserRoles]([SystemUserId],[RoleId],[SystemUserRoleId])
 VALUES ([Id of user] ,[Id of role], NEWID())
```

Comment: Thanks. It did work! Just needed to be a little patient. Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 1):

**Don't do it!**

Permissions are managed exclusively within the application. Doing this via direct SQL is utterly unsupported and will end in tears. The security model at DB level is complex and undocumented. If you manipulate it manually you can be certain you will break your installation and require a full reinstall.

Hopefully, you didn't change the default roles. If this is the case, grant the default roles back to the users and then *copy* those roles as the basis of new roles for you to customise.

Most likely you've removed access to things like reading and writing of user data, core records and system settings but manually piecing this back together can be a pain.

If you've overwritten the original roles then, depending on the version of CRM 2011 that you have, you could recover the original role definitions thusly:

1. Provision a new "temp" CRM tenant
2. Create a new solution (Settings > Solutions > New)
3. Add to your new solution the default roles
4. Export the solution as an unmanaged solution (zip file)
5. import the solution to your original tenant

You should then have restored the roles and can effectively start again with your security customisation.

Comment: The problem is we can't log into the application, not even with the administrator. So is the only alternative to use the latest back-up, or what?

Comment: The System Administrator role cannot be edited so I'm surprised that you've got to that point. Is it possible to log in using the user that originally installed CRM?

Comment: Everybody who tries to login get the error message: insufficient permissions. We downloaded a program that could give us error-messages as a txt file. It gives the feedback that there are wrong security roles. That's why we thought we might be able to restore some tables at database level.

Comment: I'm unsure how you've managed to lock out the admin user :-/ Did you explicitly remove System Admin permissions from that user (I don't even think that is possible to be honest). If you get that sorted then you're on the road to recovery. The program you mentioned - does this give you access to the CRM Trace Log? If so, can you publish a snippet of it here showing your error?

Comment: I din't do it on purpose:( And I to, have read that it should be impossible, but it is not..unfortunately.. Do you think it is possible to recover the system admin from the sql?

Comment: I've added some SQL to original answer. Look the other way while you run it ;)

Comment: I looked the other way..  but went into some troubles. The first went fine. The second got two results. I took the first (and later the second, when the first didn’t work). The third gave 0, so everything this far. The fourth changed one value, but I could still not login..

Comment: OK, let's refocus and look specifically at the error message you are receiving. Can you post details from the Trace? You should also remove the two records you created in SQL just now. As an aside, I find it odd that you have two users with the same domain name in the user table...

Answer (score 0):

Before attempting the steps below, I would create a new tenant just to make sure your master database / AD environment is still functional.  If that works, then I would attempt to recover from a backup.

If you have a database backup from before the change, you can use [the Import Organization process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127042.aspx) and that should return you to the previous state.  You will want to make a backup of your tenant and master databases before beginning.

1. Drop the tenant database
2. Restore the tenant database

If it's still not working:

1. Delete the tenant from the Deployment Manager (you have to disable it first)
2. Use the Import Organization process to re-create the tenant

If that doesn't do it, you can [rebuild from scratch](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699759)